# Rigid body translation and the moment about a point

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

ok the statement of the moments , beside the fourth  car image 
How there is a moment about the point A although there is only translational motion , is not the car only moving and not rotating ? 
why we do not say that 
5 W = 12 NB